# what's the best solution to split a .tex file into separate compiled files?

Tags: pdftex, chapters

I have a .tex file that includes several chapters (all through the `\input` command). I would like to run `pdflatex` in one command such that it saves each chapter into a separate PDF file, while maintaining correct references to sections, bibliography (that appears in the end) and so on. Is that possible?